# How do declare the type of a re-exported plain js function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a helper file, "db.ts" that re-exports some plain javascript functions from other (external) libraries. For example:

```
export { WHERE } from "pg-sql-helpers";
```

How do I declare the type of this one function? I tried:

```
export declare function WHERE(ident: any, params?: any, options?: any);
```

But this results in a conflict: "Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'WHERE'"